# List Comprehensions method to generate a sequence of random and unique numbers

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am writing a programme to generate 6 numbers (lotto style). I want to then generate a second number and compare the two and see how long it takes (in terms of counts) before the two sets of numbers match.

This is my code :

```
import random

range_of_numbers = [i for i in range(1,60)]

def draw_a_ticket():
    total_numbers = range_of_numbers = [i for i in range(1,60)]
    draw = []
    i = 0
    while i < 6:
        num = random.choice(total_numbers)
        total_numbers.remove(num)
        draw.append(num)
        i += 1
    return draw

draw = draw_a_ticket()
draw1 = draw_a_ticket()
counter = 0
while draw[0:2] != draw1[0:2]: # I am using [0:2] to reduce the complexity/find match sooner
    counter += 1
    draw = draw1
    draw1 = draw_a_ticket()

print(f"{counter} : Draw:{draw} - Draw1:{draw1}")
```

The code above works fine. But I am trying to be more pythonic and use list comprehensions to generate the numbers sets.

Ive tried the following - but I get an invalid syntax:

```
draw = [i = set(random.randint(1,60)) in range(1,7)]
print(draw)
```

The key features I am trying to achieve in a list comprehension is to:

1. generate 6 unique random integers between 1 and 59
2. store these in a list.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I only added my answer because it was almost done, and for completeness - @Belhadjer's answer is far simpler.

Comment: Beware that `randint` will return a number between 1 and 60 inclusive, whereas `range` here will return a range of numbers from 1 to 59, excluding 60.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second approach is fine, except for that you are trying to do assignment in a list comprehension and converting an int from `random.randint` to a `set`. Your `draw_ticket` function should be like this:

```py
def draw_ticket():
    numbers = list(range(0, 60)) # no need for a list comprehension to get a list from a
                                 # range - just convert it directly
    draw = [numbers.pop(numbers.index(random.choice(numbers))) + 1 for n in range(6)]
    return draw
```

Above code is not easy to understand (as most list comprehensions), so I made an easy-to-understand-version below:

```py
def draw_ticket():
    numbers = list(range(0, 60))
    draw = []
    for n in range(6): # iterate 6 times
        index = numbers.index(random.choice(numbers))                               
        number = numbers.pop(index)
        draw.append(number)
    return draw
```

So that's what the above list comprehension does.

Comment: Your list comprehension has `for n in numbers` instead of `for n in range(6)`.

Comment: @kaya3 omg, did I forget to correct this ? Thanks !

Comment: Also this is going to have problems because `pop` takes an index, but `random.choice` returns a value, not an index. So you aren't necessarily removing the right value.

Comment: @kaya3 As long as the list begins with 0 and increases by 1 for each item, the value and the index _will_ be the same ;)

Comment: Not after you've removed one element from the list, it won't... have you tried testing your code?

Comment: Thanks very much - the answer really helped.

Comment: @kaya3 hmmm … thats a good point, thanks for that. And no I didn't test my code, shame on me

Comment: Actually I tested this and it works a few times then I get a IndexError: pop index out of range.: numbers = list(range(0, 60))
draw3 = [numbers.pop(random.choice(numbers)) + 1 for n in range(6)]
print(draw3)

Comment: @milesabc123 that's because you used the old version of my code - please try the new version

Answer (score 2):

for your question generate 6 unique random integers between 1 and 59 and store them in list you can use **random.sample()**

> Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population
> sequence or set. Used for random sampling without replacement.

try this :

```
draw=random.sample(range(1,59),6)
```

for all your program you can do it like this :

```
import random

def draw_a_ticket():
    return random.sample(range(1,60),6)

draw = draw_a_ticket()
draw1 = draw_a_ticket()
counter = 0
while draw[0:2] != draw1[0:2]: # I am using [0:2] to reduce the complexity/find match sooner
    counter += 1
    draw = draw1
    draw1 = draw_a_ticket()

print(f"{counter} : Draw:{draw} - Draw1:{draw1}")
```

if you want your program select draw only once you can append the generated draw to a list of selected draws :

like this :

```
import random

selected_draw=[]
def draw_a_ticket():
    draw=random.sample(range(1,60),6)
    if draw in selected :
        draw_a_ticket()
    selected_draw.append(draw)
    return draw

draw = draw_a_ticket()
draw1 = draw_a_ticket()
counter = 0
while draw[0:2] != draw1[0:2]: # I am using [0:2] to reduce the complexity/find match sooner
    counter += 1
    draw = draw1
    draw1 = draw_a_ticket()

print(f"{counter} : Draw:{draw} - Draw1:{draw1}")
```

Comment: Cheers thanks, so the  draw = random.sample(range(1,59),6) forces the results to be unique?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who responded, really appreciated the suggestions.
Ive kind of pieced all the answers together and come up with a version of the programme that doesn't use the function but seems to work ok:

```
import random

draw = list(set([(random.randint(1,60)) for i in range(1,7)]))
draw1 = list(set([(random.randint(1,60)) for i in range(1,7)]))
counter = 0
while draw[0:2] != draw1[0:2]: # using [0:2] reduces the complexity
    counter += 1
    draw = draw1
    draw1 = list(set([(random.randint(1,60)) for i in range(1,7)]))

print(f"{counter} : Draw:{draw} - Draw1:{draw1}")
```

Thanks again.